# How to convert array in codeigniter to get data in google charts

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am converting array in codeigniter to use in google charts. The format of the converted array i want is

```
['July', 200],['Aug', 100],['Sep', 80],['Oct', 90]
```

But i am getting this [{"July":200,"Aug":100,"Sep":80,"Oct":90}] by doing

```
$series_data[] = array(
  'July' => 200,
  'Aus'  => 100,
  'Sep'  => 80,
  'Oct'  => 90
);
$data['series_data'] = json_encode($series_data);
```

Could someone please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Hey new Contributor :) What exactly is your desired output? `{"July":200,"Aug":100,"Sep":80,"Oct":90}` Is a perfectly fine JSON object and is the expected output of that `json_encode($series_data);`

Comment: @Elias I want like this ['July', 200],['Aug', 100],['Sep', 80],['Oct', 90] because of google chart two columns requirments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it correct you want something like:

```
[
  ["July",200],
  ["Aus",100],
  ["Sep",80]
]
```

Then you simply need to do:

```
$series_data = [
  ["July",200],
  ["Aus",100],
  ["Sep",80]
];
```

And `json_encode` that.

Comment: This is the most simplest one and it works great. Thanks @Elias

Answer (score 0):

You could map over the associate data to change the format, like so:

```php
$data = [
    'July' => 200,
    'Aus' => 100,
    'Sep' => 80,
    'Oct' => 90,
];

$series_data = array_map(function ($key, $value) {
    return [$key, $value];
}, array_keys($data), $data);

// outputs [["July",200],["Aus",100],["Sep",80],["Oct",90]]
```

Comment: Then i need to echo $series_data i guess?

Comment: Sorry but i am not familiar with the array_map